# Получение нужного количества повторений Python

Tags: python, for

Как мне получить нужное количество повторений в цикле for.
Мне нужно что-бы цикл повторялся достаточное для сортировки количество раз в зависимости от количества элементов в списке но при этом не вызывал ошибки о переполнении индекса числа в списке.

```
Number_massive = input("Enter number massive... ")
N_l = Number_massive.split(", ")
print(len(N_l))
i = 0
ii = 0
for i in range(len(N_l) - 1):
    if N_l[ii + i] > N_l[ii + (i + 1)]:
        N_l[ii + i], N_l[ii + (i + 1)] = N_l[ii + (i + 1)], N_l[ii + i]
    i + 1
print(N_l)
```

Comment: Для реализации [пузырьковой сортировки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC) требуется организовать 2 цикла, а у вас 1.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто использовать функцию сортировки sorted() или sort():

```
Number_massive = input("Enter number massive... ")
N_l = Number_massive.split(", ")
N_l = [int(x) for x in N_l]  # Преобразуем из str в int

sorted_list = sorted(N_l)
print(sorted_list)
```